# How to disable/enable the mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

i cannot able to disable a trigger

DISABLE TRIGGER mytable_upd_trg ON leads

The error which i received

> DISABLE TRIGGER mytable_upd_trg ON leads

MySQL said: Documentation

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'DISABLE TRIGGER mytable_upd_trg ON leads' at line 1

Comment: Do you want to temporarily disable the trigger or do you want to delete the trigger permanently?

Answer (score 3):

You can't temporarily disable triggers. You can remove triggers permanently with DROP TRIGGER ...

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a variable and an IF clause in the trigger to disable it.